# Tool to generate beautiful PDF's from a list of data?

Tags: pdf, data-visualization, data

We need to generate a lot of PDF files, based on a simple template (preferably one we can make ourself, but an existing library could work too). Each time we need to input 5-10 data.

We would of course do this ourself each time in Indesign/Photoshop/Whatever, but it's quite time consuming and we need someone with this tool.

I would imagine there are tools that support the flow:

1. Upload your own PDF template of pick from library
2. Click "create doc" and you enter 5 data
3. You click download

And you got a fresh PDF file with the data.

Does this exist? :)

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth looking at [Docmosis](https://www.docmosis.com) which works from Word or Open Document Text (ODT) templates and can create PDF results.  Since you are creating beautiful (brochure style maybe) PDFs, then ODT is a good template format to use in this case because the layout requirements will need to be tight and accurately transformed into PDF.

The process would be to upload your ODT template(s) to the Docmosis cloud, then make REST calls / HTTP calls with your data (XML or JSON) to have the PDFs created.  This can be done from computer programs (if you are integrating) or from simple HTML forms if you are running by hand.

It might also be worth looking at [Adobe LiveCycle](http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/modules-displayTab2.html#PDFGenerator) which has a PDF assembly service.  I haven't used it, but Adobe do know PDF very well!.

Please note I work for Docmosis.
I hope that helps.